# performSegueWithIdentifier without storyboard idendentifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've a `UITableViewController` with dynamics rows, for every row, I need to open a new `viewcontroller`.
I've tried to use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but it doesn't works because I don't have storyboard identifier.

How to open a new `viewcontroller` dynamically?

I've tried with:

```
newUiViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: there is in storyboard a UIViewcontroller called "controller" ?

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens? Any error messages or stack traces?  Did you check to see if 'controller' is nil?

Comment: the error message is: "reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fc639c37420>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'controller'"

Comment: @Ilario in storyboard I've a view called  newUiViewController but I don't have controller identifier

Answer (score 1):

You should give a controller identifier in your storyboard, check this:

[image]

Class is your "newUiViewController" and Storyboard ID "menu" is your "controller"

then you can do:

```
newUiViewController *controller = (newUiViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: done, but now I don't have any exception, and nothing happens

Comment: probably I need to change appdelegate file. How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution.
Like navcontroller I'm using "SWRevealViewController", so the correct code is:

```
UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
[navController setViewControllers: @[list] animated: YES];

[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

I think that is useful for other